# How to use Microsoft Graph API to get all the groups for Authorization in .net core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, authorization, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on .net core project. I am trying to implement authorize using AD groups. My requirement is, I have many groups in the azure ad. If the current user belongs to any of the available groups in azure ad then I want to authorize those users to access apis written in .net core application. I tried as below. I have added below two classes

```
 public class IsMemberOfGroupHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IsMemberOfGroupRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
            AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsMemberOfGroupRequirement requirement)
        {
            var groupClaim = context.User.Claims
                 .FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "groups" &&
                     claim.Value.Equals(requirement.GroupId, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

            if (groupClaim != null)
                context.Succeed(requirement);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

 public class IsMemberOfGroupRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public readonly string GroupId;
        public readonly string GroupName;

        public IsMemberOfGroupRequirement(string groupName, string groupId)
        {
            GroupName = groupName;
            GroupId = groupId;
        }
    }
```

Below is my startup class.

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                var adGroupConfig = new List<AdGroupConfig>();
                _configuration.Bind("AdGroups", adGroupConfig);

                foreach (var adGroup in adGroupConfig)
                    options.AddPolicy(
                        adGroup.GroupName,
                        policy =>
                            policy.AddRequirements(new IsMemberOfGroupRequirement(adGroup.GroupName, adGroup.GroupId)));
            });
```

Above code checks groups available in configuration file. Now my requirement is use microsoft graph api to get all the available groups. I could not find any way to handle this requirement. Can someone help me with this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please firstly check [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/886f2ad2bf6add922c7998fb592e3d4088f9cf4e/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups) , which use OpenID Connect to sign in users and use MSAL to get the Microsoft Graph API token to retire groups .

If config the your application to receive group claims by editing the manifest :

```
{
  ...
  "errorUrl": null,
  "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
  ...
}
```

The object id of the security groups the signed in user is member of is returned in the groups claim of the token.

> If a user is member of more groups than the overage limit (150 for SAML tokens, 200 for JWT tokens), then the Microsoft Identity Platform does not emit the groups claim in the token. Instead, it includes an overage claim in the token that indicates to the application to query the Graph API to retrieve the user’s group membership.

```
{
  ...
  "_claim_names": {
    "groups": "src1"
    },
    {
   "_claim_sources": {
    "src1": {
        "endpoint":"[Graph Url to get this user's group membership from]"
        }
    }
  ...
}
```

So you can follow the process :

> 1. Check for the claim _claim_names with one of the values being groups. This indicates overage.
> 2. If found, make a call to the endpoint specified in _claim_sources to fetch user’s groups.
> 3. If none found, look into the groups claim for user’s groups.

Of course , you can directly call Microsoft Graph API to retire current user's groups **without** using `group claims` :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

You can then authorize based on that groups . For example , if using policy :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("GroupsCheck", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupsCheckRequirement("YourGroupID")));
});
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, GroupsCheckHandler>();
```

GroupsCheckRequirement.cs:

```
public class GroupsCheckRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string groups;

    public GroupsCheckRequirement(string groups)
    {
        this.groups = groups;
    }
}
```

GroupsCheckHandler.cs :

```
public class GroupsCheckHandler : AuthorizationHandler<GroupsCheckRequirement>
{
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition;
    private readonly IMSGraphService graphService;

    public GroupsCheckHandler(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, IMSGraphService MSGraphService)
    {
        this.tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        this.graphService = MSGraphService;
    }
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                              GroupsCheckRequirement requirement)
    {
        string accessToken = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUserAsync(new[] { Constants.ScopeUserRead, Constants.ScopeDirectoryReadAll });

        User me = await graphService.GetMeAsync(accessToken);

        IList<Group> groups = await graphService.GetMyMemberOfGroupsAsync(accessToken);

        var result = false;
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            if (requirement.groups.Equals(group.Id))
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }

        if (result)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
       
    }


}
```

And then using policy :

```
[Authorize(Policy = "GroupsCheck")]
```

Comment: Hey thanks. Very useful. One thing I am not very much clear. "_claim_names": {
    "groups": "src1"
    },
    May I know what is this and where I have to add this?

Comment: That is a claim in token which returned from Azure AD If you use group claims but group accounts overage limit . If using graph api , you don't need to concern that .

Comment: Thanks. Just want to know Is there any way to get group names in jwt token?

Comment: Just use group claims if you want to include the jwt token . But it has limit for large number of groups.

Comment: I have limited number of groups. I tried adding "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",. This returns me group ids but I want to get group names. Is there any way?

Comment: @Niranjan No, just id . If you want name , still need to call microsoft graph api to get group details with id .

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get all the groups the user is a direct member of.

```
GET /me/memberOf
```

In .net-core you can use [GraphServiceClient](https://briantjackett.com/2018/12/13/introduction-to-calling-microsoft-graph-from-a-c-net-core-application/) to call graph api. Here is a sample for your reference.

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        // Get back the access token.
                        var accessToken = "";

                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                        {
                            // Configure the HTTP bearer Authorization Header
                            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Invalid authorization context");
                        }

                        return (Task.FromResult(0));
                    }
                    ));
            var groups = graphClient.Me.MemberOf.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tony Ju. May I know where I have to add above code. I want to implement authorization based on groups.

Comment: @Niranjan Take a look at this article about the authorization. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/

Comment: @Niranjan Above code is to get the available groups for a user by using Graph api.

Comment: @Niranjan I'm having the same problems as you had some years ago, where did you put above code?