# MVC Core + Azure Active Directory Get Groups from GraphAPI

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

I am trying to implement authentication in an MVC Core 2.2 application using Azure Active Directory by following this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core-2-0-using-azure-active-director/).

I have configured the manifest appropriately by setting the “groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup" but am still not getting the groups as part of the user claims. It appears that I should be getting something like this

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/
[image]

when inspecting the claims however all I appear to be getting is "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid:"

[image]

It seems that if the user has more than 4 groups assigned that they

[will not be sent as part of the token.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/6996) and that one would need to use the GraphAPI to pull the groups for the user.

I cannot seem to find any resources that illustrate how to accomplish this and get it to work with

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {

            options.AddPolicy("Editor", policy => policy.RequireClaim("groups","XXXXXXXXXXXX"));

        });
```

Can someone possibly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good answer on this @[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091323/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-api-to-get-all-the-groups-for-authorization-in-net-c).

It however suggests you to get all the group membership for a given user - which might not be efficient if user has large number of group memberships.

You can instead use the [checkMemberGroups api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-checkmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). It can take up to 20 group ids for each call which should be good enough for most of the cases.

Comment: those were great resources. Thank you!