# OpenIDConnectAuthentication is not working with some users in the Azure Active Directory

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

I have two AD groups in azure `K100User` and `K100Admin`. The below code is working fine however, This code is not working for the users who are part of more than 200 AD groups.

```
private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;
private static string k100User = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["K100User"];
private static string k100Admin = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["K100Admin"];

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity1 = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true
        },
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            SecurityTokenValidated = (ctx) =>
            {
                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                var claims = ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindAll("groups");
                var appRoles = new List<Claim>();
                foreach (var item in claims)
                {
                    var groupStringValue = item.Value;
                    if (groupStringValue == k100Admin)
                    {
                        appRoles.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "K100Admin", ClaimValueTypes.String));
                    }
                    else if (groupStringValue == k100User)
                    {
                        appRoles.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "K100User", ClaimValueTypes.String));
                    }

                }
                if (appRoles.Count > 0)
                {
                    ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(appRoles[0]);
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you are not getting some of the Azure AD service limits and restrictions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-service-limits-restrictions

Comment: Btw. what is the main goal of that code?

Comment: @LukeDuda Please help me to modify this code, it it not working for the users who are part of more than 200 AD groups

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Groups overage claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens):

[image]

In your scene, the user is member of more than 200 groups, so you need to check for the claim `_claim_names` with one of the values being groups. If found, make a call to the endpoint specified in `_claim_sources` to fetch user’s groups.

You can also choose to directly call Microsoft Graph [List memberOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get the groups.

A similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091323/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-api-to-get-all-the-groups-for-authorization-in-net-c?answertab=votes#tab-top) for your reference.

Comment: i did not understand it. i am new to Azure AD and oAuth :(

Comment: @ILYASKHAN In you code , you are getting the `groups` claim by using `var claims = ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindAll("groups");`. But if the user is member of more than 200 groups, there won't be a `groups` claim. There should be a `_claim_names` claim instead. You should find this claim and make a call to the `endpoint` to fetch the user's group.

Comment: I have pasted the modified code above, please check. Is it the way you want me to change it?

Comment: IEnumerable<Claim> claims = ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims;
  Claim objectAdmin = claims.First(claim => claim.Value == k100Admin);
 if (objectAdmin != null) {appRoles.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "K100Admin", ClaimValueTypes.String));}
  if (appRoles.Count > 0){ctx.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(appRoles[0]);}
 return Task.FromResult(0);

Comment: @ILYASKHAN No. You should check the `_claim_names` claim instead of `groups` in your code. And it will ask you to call Microsoft Graph to get the groups. So The recommended method is to call Microsoft Graph directly. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091323/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-api-to-get-all-the-groups-for-authorization-in-net-c?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Thanks i have checked the link, my project is of asp.net MVC and its not a core. will that code be helpful to me?