# Authorize web api with Azure Active Directory Groups C#

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building a web API with .net core 3.1, I secured it with Azure Active Directory. The web API controllers should be authorized based on azure active directory groups. I get users groups in the access_token but I need to check those groups with MS Graph API because sometimes a user could have more than 200 groups and his token groups would be empty. I don't know how to do that with MS Graph API

My Contorller

```
[Authorize(Policy = "UserGroup")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult Get()
   {
    return Ok("value");
   }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd");            
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Countries",
                    policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups",
                    Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureSecurityGroup:UserGroup")));
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
      "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "ClientId": "my-client-id",
      "ClientSecret": "my-client-secret",
      "Domain": "mydomain.com",
      "TenantId": "my-Tenant-id"
    },
  "AzureSecurityGroup": {
      "UserGroup": "ExampleGroupID"
   }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a user could have more than 200 groups, you can check `_claim_names` and make a call to the endpoint under `_claim_sources` to fetch the groups of the user.

You can also directly call Microsoft Graph API to retire current user's groups and authorize based on that groups.

Sample code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091323/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-api-to-get-all-the-groups-for-authorization-in-net-c?answertab=votes#tab-top) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks but I IMSGraphService does not exist in any namespace, is it a custom interface?

Comment: @DainaHodges It should be included in the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/886f2ad2bf6add922c7998fb592e3d4088f9cf4e/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups) mentioned at the beginning in that answer.